# Caracteres iguales en una ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

estoy empezando en la programación en Java y me gustaría saber cómo puedo lograr identificar hasta que posición de un dato que contiene una ArrayList es igual al siguiente dato de la misma ArrayList y así sucesivamente, para que me entiendan mejor pondré una parte del código que tengo:

```
public class EncontrarIguales {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList();
    
    al.add("01010110");
    al.add("01010010");
    al.add("01011000");
    al.add("01011001");
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores que tiene el arreglo son: "+al);
}
```

}

Bueno, con los datos anteriores, lo que quiero lograr es que el programa me diga que los caracteres que comparten todos los datos de la Array List son `0101` y que la posición del último caracter dentro de la ArrayList es la posición 3.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que trabajar con 2 for anidados, el primer for para recorrer cada elemento del ArrayList y el segundo for para comparar cada caracter del primer elemento del ArrayList con cada caracter de los demás elementos.

```
        ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList();

        al.add("01010110");
        al.add("01010010");
        al.add("01011000");
        al.add("01011001"); 

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores que tiene el arreglo son: "+al);        
        
        int posicion;
        int longitud;
        String cadena="";
        longitud=al.get(0).length();        
        //Recorremos cada elemento del ArrayList
        for(int i=1;i<al.size();i++){
            cadena="";
            posicion=0;
            /*Recorremos cada caracter del primer elemento, sin son iguales concatenamos a una cadena
             si no son iguales paramos el bucle
               
             */
            for(int m=0;m<longitud;m++){  
               //comparamos si los caracteres son iguales              
                if(al.get(0).charAt(m)==al.get(i).charAt(m)){
                    cadena=cadena+al.get(0).charAt(m);                    
                    posicion++; 
                }
                
                else{                   
                   longitud=posicion-1;
                   break;
                } 
            }             
        }        
        System.out.println("Caracteres que comparten todos los datos: "+cadena);
        System.out.println("Posición del último caracter: "+(longitud-1));
```

Pongamos el siguiente caso

```
al.add("01234567");
al.add("01231000");
al.add("01234510");
```

Observamos que al comparar el primer elemento del arreglo con el segundo elemento del arreglo tienen componentes iguales hasta la 4ta posición, y al comparar el primer elemento del arreglo con el tercer elemento del arreglo tienen componentes iguales hasta la 6ta posición, entonces al realizar la comparación del primer elemento del arreglo con el segundo elemento del arreglo tiene que haber una variable que controle el for interno para que al comparar el primer elemento del arreglo con el tercer elemento del arreglo solo recorra hasta la 4ta posición.  Esto se realiza en el fragmento del código

```
if(al.get(0).charAt(m)==al.get(i).charAt(m)){
     cadena=cadena+al.get(0).charAt(m);                    
     posicion++; 
}

else{                   
    longitud=posicion-1;
    break;
}
```